# Get method in php then pass the value into json format

Tags: javascript, php, json, chart.js

i'm trying to access the value that i've got from get method in my php file. My PHP file would looks like this

```
<?php
include 'Con.php';
header('content-Type: application/json');

$catid = $_GET["CatId"];    

//array declaration
$array  = array();

//declaration for the index name of the array
$text1 = "data1";
$text2 = "data2";
$text3 = "data3";
$text4 = "data4";
$text5 = "data5";


$sql = "select `Total Cliks`,`Categories_idCategories`,`Month` from Clicks where Categories_idCategories in ($catid)";
$_sql = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

foreach ($_sql as $result) {
    $Clicks = $result['Total Cliks'];
    $Categories_idCategories = $result['Categories_idCategories'];
    $Month = $result ['Month'];

    if(array_key_exists($Month, $array[$text1]) == false){
        $array[$text1][$Month] = $Clicks;   
    }
    elseif(array_key_exists($Month, $array[$text2]) == false){
        $array[$text2][$Month] = $Clicks;   
    }
    elseif(array_key_exists($Month, $array[$text3]) == false){
        $array[$text3][$Month] = $Clicks;   
    }
    elseif(array_key_exists($Month, $array[$text4]) == false){
        $array[$text4][$Month] = $Clicks;   
    }
    elseif(array_key_exists($Month, $array[$text5]) == false){
        $array[$text5][$Month] = $Clicks;   
    }


}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

and then in my Javascricpt file i wanted to make the reference url same as the url that i already get in "get method" in php

so the javascript code would look like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8888/ClicksChart/ckbox.php?CatId <?php     $_GET["CatId"];?>",
    type : "GET",
    success : function(array){
        console.log(array);

        alert('Welcome');
```

In the URL, i wanted to have the url same as the value of my "Get method"
For example : in my get method i have got http://localhost:8888/ClicksChart/ckbox.php?CatId =1,2,3". so the url in the javascript file same as the value of the PHP file.
is there any way to solve this? thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

your parameter is missing in ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8888/ClicksChart/ckbox.php?CatId=<?php echo $_GET['CatId'];?>",
    type : "GET",
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(array){
        console.log(array);

        alert('Welcome');
```

Comment: can you give me the example code? because i am quite new to programming. thank you

Comment: "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" in the line number 2

Comment: url : "http://localhost:8888/ClicksChart/ckbox.php?CatId=<?php echo $_GET['CatId'];?>",
It is the issue with " quotes

Comment: do i need to write any references for the javascript file, so it will refer to php correct php file that have "Get Method"?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write echo

```
url : "http://localhost:8888/ClicksChart/ckbox.php?CatId=<?php echo $_GET['CatId'];?>",
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an '=' and an 'echo'

```
$.ajax({
url : "http://localhost:8888/ClicksChart/ckbox.php?CatId=<?php echo $_GET["CatId"];?>",
```